# Вертикально выровнять текст в CSS

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Всем привет!

Есть сайт - https://swiftagency.ru/

Нужно выровнять элемент **cheat__text** по вертикали, чтобы текст в карточках находился по центру.

Answer (score 0):

Создайте для каждого элемента с классом cheat__text родителя в виде нового контейнера.
Добавьте новому контейнеру стили:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
flex-grow: 1;
```